# google-cloud-vision for internal photo repository

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Is it possible to use the google-cloud-vision API to match photos with an internal photo directory or sharepoint? The purpose is to find the best match between a specific photo and the existing photos in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically speaking, I don't see why not. The API, depending on how you want to use it, has certain requirements. For example, [this API post request](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/request) needs a image in String format. As long as you write a piece of code to pull and convert your image into String format (base64), it works. You can pull the image from the internet or from Google Cloud Storage or your own local machine (as the example mentioned). The API doesn't know nor care about the original location of the image.